# What is the s modifier in DAEMON_OPTIONS?

Tags: sendmail

I have been reading on how to configure sendmail as a smtps server. I have a personal rule through that I never enter anything into a configuration file unless I understand what it does. While for many aspects of what I've been reading I've been able to look up it's function I've found one that I cannot find any documentation for.

Many tutorials have a line similar to this line in their `sendmail.cf` file:

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=SMTPS-v4, Port=smtps, Modifiers=Eas)dnl
```

Every part of that I can look up and understand except the `s` modifier. I have found a [couple](http://www.sendmail.org/~gshapiro/8.10.Training/DaemonPortOptions.html) of [web pages](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Sendmail/Part+III+The+Configuration+File/Chapter+24.+The+O+Options+Configuration+Command/DaemonPortOptions/) that outline the available modifiers, none that show what the `s` modifier does.

I would guess based on how [this documentation](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Sendmail/Part+III+The+Configuration+File/Chapter+24.+The+O+Options+Configuration+Command/DaemonPortOptions/) defines `S` that the lowercase `s` forces TLS to be enabled but not with enough confidence that I am ready to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The `s` flag enables the obsolete SMTP/SSL(465) protocol. It's been replaced by a combination of TLS over SMTP(25) and TLS over Submission(587).

As at January 2018 the relevant reference documentation is [RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314).